# Reading updated Realm ThreadSafeReference on background queue

Tags: swift, realm

According to [the Realm docs on threading](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#seeing-changes-from-other-threads):

> When you initially open a Realm on a thread, its state will be based off the **most recent successful write commit**

[And](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest#passing-instances-across-threads):

> Failing to resolve a ThreadSafeReference will result in the source version of the Realm **being pinned** until the reference is deallocated.

This gives a bit confusing results when used together. If a `ThreadSafeReference` is **asynchronously** resolved on a background queue it shows old (pinned) values. But if a `ThreadSafeReference` is **synchronously** resolved it shows updated values.

Let's say I have a simple Realm Object: `MyObject` with a single `name` property:

```swift
// setup, create object with name: "a"
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.my", qos: .default, attributes: [])
let obj = MyObject(name: "a")
try realm.write { realm.add(obj) }

// get reference (deliberately created before update)
let ref = ThreadSafeReference(to: obj)

// update name to "b" (main queue, or .sync on other queue)
try realm.write {
    obj.name = "b"
}

// async resolve on background thread
queue.async {
    let r = try! Realm()
    let o = r.resolve(ref)!

    XCTAssertEqual("b", o.name) // fails, o.name == "a"

    r.refresh()

    XCTAssertEqual("b", o.name) // succeeds
}
```

Compared to:

```
// setup, create object with name: "a"
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.app.my", qos: .default, attributes: [])
let obj = MyObject(name: "a")
try realm.write { realm.add(obj) }

// get reference (deliberately created before update)
let ref = ThreadSafeReference(to: obj)

// update name to "b" (main queue, or .sync on other queue)
try realm.write {
    obj.name = "b"
}

// sync resolve on background thread
queue.sync {
    let r = try! Realm()
    let o = r.resolve(ref)!

    XCTAssertEqual("b", o.name) // succeeds
}
```

If `queue.sync` is used instead of `queue.async` the Realm doesn't need to be refreshed manually, and the resolved reference immediately shows the updated `"b"` name. This is also the case when the realm is *queried* for `MyObject` instead of resolving the reference.

So what exactly is the behaviour of `ThreadSafeReferences`? It looks like it sometimes keeps pinned values, but sometimes doesn't. Why is it necessary to refresh the Realm in this case when it should be based on the 'most recent successful write commit'?

Comment: I am not sure I follow the question; if you want to run a time-consuming function on a background thread (like writing 2Gb of data) you would enclose it in a background Dispatch queue like this `DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {` which is kinda what you have. Within that queue though, all of the data should be encapsulated in an autorelease pool so objects can be deallocated when not in use. Also .default has a higher priority than background tasks so is that what you want to use? Also when XCTAssertEqual fails what is the nature of the failure?

Comment: Also... The placement of the `let ref = ThreadSafeReference(to: obj)` should be after the second write - the XCTAssertEqual call will then show they are equal.

Comment: @Jay This is just an example to showcase my question (the `autorelease` and `.default` etc. are implementation details not really relevant to this specific question I suppose, but you are correct of course). The assert fails because `o.name` is still `"a"` so the ref points to old data. The question is: is that expected behaviour? Because when using `.sync` it is updated to `"b"`. What is the difference? Why is the realm/ref up-to-date in one case but not in the other? The placement of creating the ref is deliberately *before* the update to `"b"`.

Comment: Worded differently: "state will be based off the most recent successful write commit" is not true in all cases? A ref might resolve to the pinned data at the time of creation, are there any rules that specify this behaviour?

Comment: I've been thinking about this question and as a guess, .sync ensures the work is done now, performing it on a run loop (so realm is refreshed). Whereas async does the work later, which may not be on the same runloop. In other words, synchronous (block & wait) returns when the task is completed whereas asynchronous (dispatch & proceed) function returns immediately, dispatching the task but not waiting for it to complete (not on run loop). However, I could be totally wrong.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your thoughts! Wouldn't you expect a regular query (instead of ref) to have the same behaviour in that case? If I leave everything the same in the async example but add a query right before resolving the ref (`r.objects(MyObject.self).first`) the resolved ref *does* have the updated content. So I think it has more to do with the resolving of the ref than the async/run loop behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Seen the same issue some time ago, and recently found the answer why this happens:

[Quote:]

> ... we added new object on main thread Realm and at the same time we
> are polling on background thread to get the changes but background
> Thread Realm was not notified even its `autorefresh` property is `true`
> and the answer is as documented “background threads do not have an
> active run loop and you will need to manually call `refresh()` in order
> to update to the latest version, even if `autorefresh` is set to
> `true`.”

[End of quote]

You can find the original post here by [following this link](https://medium.com/@aliakhtar_16369/concurrency-multi-threading-in-realm-realmswift-part-4-2345deabe512)

So the answer is that in order to see changes we have to manually call `Realm.refresh()` function if we operate in thread which does not have a run loop

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware that background Realms are not auto refreshed, but I don't think that's what's happening here because the background Realm is created *after* a write/update. Specifically "When you initially open a Realm on a thread, its state will be based off the most recent successful write commit" does not seem to hold up.